# How do you change the color for navbar-toggle icon when using the Designmodo's Flat UI framework?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using designmodo's Flat UI framework. I'm trying to change the navbar-toggle icon color but cannot find anywhere on how to do it. Any suggestions?

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-01">
```

Comment: Do you have a link to your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:before, { color: white; }
```